# Why is the echoing of my html file in wordpress sidebar widget breaking other widget front-side widget styling?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My use case for the WordPress plugin is quite simple. I want to provide a plugin that sets up a custom sidebar widget that a user can activate then place where ever they please (or where ever the sidebar widgets areas allow them).

The plugin provides a search functionality that does a bunch of stuff. The "search" functionality is built completely in HTML/JS.

I have gone through creating a WordPress plugin boilerplate using Alessandro Castellani youtube series called ["Wordpress Plugins Development Tutorials"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLriKzYyLb28kR_CPMz8uierDWC2y3znI2).

My folder structure more or less looks like the tutorial code that goes with the series (at least the more widget specify files). [Found Here](https://github.com/Alecaddd/WordPressPlugin101/tree/master/Lesson36)

Despite the complexity of the structure used in the tutorial and the simplistic nature of my particular use case, I like the extensibility/scalability the plugin architecture used provides. I digress.

I've created and called the proper WP_Widget class methods; widget, form, and update.

The plugin successfully instantiated the custom sidebar widget on the admin side and is able "drag and drop" as I please.

For the rendering of the front-side content, I am using *file_get_contents()* to retrieve the contents of the HTML file inside the *widget()* method. Then I echo out the contents BEFORE the *$args['after_widget']* declaration.

This is the code snippet of the widget method code.

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $searchHTML = file_get_contents(PLUGIN_URL . '/api-search.html', __FILE__);
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        //$searchHTML = file_get_contents(plugins_url('api-search.html', __FILE__));
        //echo $searchHTML;
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
```

When I check the front side, the HTML "search" functionality loads properly, as well as the adjoining JS files enqueued. It works as intended.

The issue is despite the widget loading the files like I want it to, it seems to break the other widgets.

This is how it looks like before echoing the HTML content. 
[image: Before The echo of the HTML content]

This is how it looks like after echoing the HTML content.
[image]

---

***If there are portions of my code I should provide to troubleshoot this, let me know and I will happily do so. At the moment, can't think of any other methods used would be the issue.***
EDIT: Portions of my SO edits are not saving!

---

EDIT: Adding the entire code of "api-search.html". I should mention that this code is strickly prototype and has not been cleaned up... obviously lol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>MBE AUTOCOMPLETE</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />

    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css"
      integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mbe-style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="/assets/scripts/mbe-api-functions.js"
    ></script>

    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Thasadith');
        </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"> function hideSelectSubModal() {
      $("#selectSubcategory").modal("hide");
    }

    //$("#modal").on("load", createRadioButtonFromArray(subList));
    function getCategory() {
      let output = autocomplete();
      $(function() {
        $("#industry").autocomplete({
          source: output
        });
      });
      $("#industry").on("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
        getSubList();
      });
    }

    function getSubList() {
      $("#industry").autocomplete({
        select: populateModal()
      });
    }</script>
  </head>
  <body class="mbe-plugin">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <form role="form">
          <label for="industry">Search For Professional: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="param"
            id="industry"
            oninput="getCategory()"
            size="30"
          />
          <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#selectSubcategory"
              onclick="populateModal()"
            >
              Find
            </button>
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> -->
          </td>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- First Modal: selectSubcategory -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="selectSubcategory"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="selectSubcategoryLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="selectSubcategoryLabel"></h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="select_subcategory" onclick="getCheckBox()"></form>
              <!--
                <input class="form-control" type="radio" id="subcategory_list"> </select>
              -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Inbetween -->
      <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="inBetween"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="inBetweenLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="inBetweenLabel">Just a few question:</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p> This is to better connect you with a proffesional, we will not sell your information.<p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="initQuestionDisplay()">Save changes</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-- Form submission modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="formSubmit"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="formSubmitLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="formSubmitLabel">
                Enter your information
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="post" data-email="mbetestemail@gmail.com" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyBzmpwpTU9vPWVDE_p8KQI-_ZjWTdlJOJ-FZ41/exec">
                  <form class="gform pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="post" data-email="mbetestemail@gmail.com" action="CALL TO GOOGLE SCRIPT FILE">
                      <div class="form-elements">
                        <div class=" pure-g">
                          <!-- <fieldset class="pure-group"> -->
                          <fieldset class="pure-u-1-2 pure-u-md-1-3">
                            <label for="name">Name: </label>
                            <input id="name" class="pure-u-23-24" name="name" placeholder="Full name!" />
                          </fieldset>

                          <!-- <fieldset class="pure-group"> -->
                          <fieldset class="pure-u-1-2 pure-u-md-1-3">
                              <label for="email">Email:</label>
                              <input id="email" class="pure-u-23-24" name="email" type="email" value=""
                              required placeholder="your.name@email.com"/>
                              <span class="email-invalid" style="display:none">
                                Must be a valid email address</span>
                            </fieldset>

                          <fieldset class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                              <label for="name">Phone Number: </label>
                              <input id="phone_number" class="pure-u-23-24" name="phone_number" placeholder="Name of your company or company you work for" />
                            </fieldset>

                          <fieldset id="form-answer-box" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                              <label for="answers"></label>
                              <!-- Shouldnt be input, insert data into a tag tag dynamically? with inner or cosument.write then hide -->
                              <input id="answer-field" class="pure-u-23-24" name="answer-field" placeholder="Name of your company or company you work for" />
                            </fieldset>


                        </div>

                          <button class="button-success pure-button button-xlarge" onclick="initResultDisplay()">
                            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thankyou_message" style="display:none;">
                            <h2><em>Thanks</em> for contacting us!
                              We will get back to you soon!</h2>
                        </div>
                    </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Questions modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="questionsDisplay"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="questionsDisplayLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="questionsDisplayLabel">
                QUESTIONS
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div
              class="modal-body"
              data-bind="template: {name: 'template', data: $data}"
            ></div>
            <script type="text/html" id="template">
              <div class="diplay-frame" data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: '_data'}">
                <div class="question-box">
                    <h2 class="question" id="ques" data-bind="text: _data['question']"/>
                    <div data-bind="foreach: {data: _data['answers'], as: 'answer'}">
                        <input type="radio" id="ans" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedAnswer, attr:{name: $parent.optionGroupName, value: $data}" />
                        <span data-bind="text: answer"/>
                    </div>


                </div>
              </div>
            </script>
               <button
                  type="button"
                  onclick="captureAnswers()"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Next
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <!-- Search result Display Modal -->
      <div
        class="modal fade"
        id="searchResultDisplay"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="searchResultDisplayLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="searchResultDisplayLabel">
                Search Results
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div
              class="modal-body"
              data-bind="template: {name: 'template1', data: $data}"
            ></div>
            <script type="text/html" id="template1">
              <div class="diplay-frame" data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: '_data'}">
                <div class="result-box">
                    <div class="bgtint"></div>
                    <section class="businesscard">
                        <div class="flip">
                            <div class="front">
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <img class="profile_image" width="50px" height="50px" data-bind="attr:{src: _data['profile_image']}"/>
                                    <a data-bind="attr:{href: _data['profile_link'], target: '_blank'}"><h2 class="user_name" data-bind="text: _data['username']"/></a>
                                    <div class="introduction"><h4 class="company_name" data-bind="text: _data['business_name']"/></div>
                                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="userinfo">
                                <div class="col-sm-4" id="phone-box">
                                    <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
                                    <p class="user_mobile" data-bind="text: _data['mobile']"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4" id="email-box">
                                    <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
                                    <p class="user_email" data-bind="text: _data['email']"/>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
              </div>
            </script>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/form-submission-handler.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include the contents of `api-search.html`.

Comment: Done! I Think I should have also added the adjoining CSS and JS files. Let me know if they would be required for troubleshooting this.

Comment: Why are you including an entire HTML page in your widget? That's what's breaking the sidebar... if you actually need the entire page, I suggest using an `iframe` to embed it instead.

Comment: lol... #facepalm,  I did that initially. What I did what has generated a button that would initiate and embed the HTML over a modal, but I did this hardcoded using custom HTML widget. I imagine there some refactoring required but how would I go about creating the initial variable input, to then pass it to the HTML file? Sorry for the noobness, php is not my forte.

Comment: If you want to embed your HTML page in an iframe (which has its own technical challenges but that's outside the scope of this question), then: `$searchHTML = '<iframe src="'. plugins_url('api-search.html', __FILE__); . '"></iframe>';` (this is all by memory, not near a computer right now to check).

Comment: Nice, I didn't think to concatenate the Iframe tag while building the $searchHTML variable. Yeah, the only challenges I'm seeing are styling and some of the Jquery autocomplete issues, seem that the modal is stealing focus. Anyways, thanks for your input.